# Connect to oracle db with javascript (node js) - require('oracledb') errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle

I would like to connect to Oracle DB with javascript, using node js.
Tried this version: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/quickstartnodeonprem.html

This is what i'd like to achive:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="example_1.js">
</script>
```

```
async function run() {

  const oracledb = require('oracledb');

  let connection;

try {
  connection = await oracledb.getConnection({ user: "testuser", password: "****", connectionString: "localhost:1521/xe" });

  console.log("Successfully connected to Oracle Database");

  await connection.execute(`begin
                                insert into test_table values(test_table_seq.nextval);
                                commit;
                            end;`);

} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
} finally {
  if (connection) {
    try {
      await connection.close();
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
}
}
```

From command line, it works as expected (node example_1.js)

From browser it not really wants to work.

1. "require is not defined" (solved maybe with this: `<script src="./require.js"></script>` )
2. Then i get "Module name "oracledb" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])"
3. When i modify the code to "const oracledb = require(['oracledb'],function(){});" i get this: "oracledb.getConnection is not a function"
4. When i try with define:

```
define('moduleTwo', function(require) {
  var namedModule = require('oracledb');
})
```

I get this: "/oracledb.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND". It seems to look for a file.

I'm a "bit" lost, any advice how to make it work?

Comment: Unless you know exactly what you're doing, a good rule of thumb is "nodejs packages don't work in browsers, only in nodejs"

Comment: Since there is a binary module for node-oracledb, it's unlikely to ever work in a browser.  You need to use it in a Node.js "mid-tier".